# How to install gdm3setup?

Tags: 12.04, installation, gdm

I found this one thing called gdm3setup and it seems like its what I want but I have no idea how to install it. I went on the github website for the project and for Ubuntu it has a set of .deb files but I do not know what to do with them. Is there a package I can download or do an 'apt-get' through terminal?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1:

Download the files and double-click them in your file manager. This should open the Ubuntu Software Center, where you can install them.

The quicker way (2:)

Download the files and install a program called gdebi. `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. Gdebi will handle dependencies for you. Then, run gdebi on the files from the terminal with `sudo gdebi ./FILE`.

You could also try your luck with just using `sudo dpkg -i ./File`, but that won't automatically resolve dependencies for you.

Comment: so i download all the files and run them each one by one?

Comment: @hassassin96 No. You just want the most recent ones. The reason there are so many is because he is storing them in that one location instead of archiving old versions. Here is the link for the one you want. https://github.com/Nano77/various/blob/master/deb/gdm3setup-debian-20130207-1.deb

Comment: when i try to do that terminal returns "Dependency is not satisfiable: gdm3"